# XML Exporting and Mapping in VBA for Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Wall of text incoming, beware.

I have a spreadsheet with, of particular importance to these functions, a number of links to a web document.  These links have an address (the base URL), a sub-address (#page=, which needs to be in the subaddress so Excel doesn't get confused by the #), and a display text which is the page number.  This spreadsheet has an XML map which someone else made.

If I export the spreadsheet to XML normally, it exports *only* the display text of a link (so, the page number, but not the actual URL).  I want the XML data to save the link rather than the display text.

The method I chose for this was to use the BeforeXMLExport and AfterXMLExport to

1. Copy the spreadsheet
2. Loop through the spreadsheet, changing the values of each cell with a hyperlink to the actual URL, rather than the display text
3. Export
4. Delete the changed spreadsheet
5. Give the copy spreadsheet the original's name and finally
6. Reapply the XML map to the spreadsheet, since it loses it during the copying process.

The main issue with this is that, since there are two spreadsheets at the time of actually importing, my XML file has a bunch of useless data - it is also exporting the spreadsheet that includes display text instead of URL.  Would copying to a different workbook, then moving that sheet to the original book avoid this issue?  If so, how would I go about that?

On a less important note, I do not think this is the most efficient method of doing this.  My particular concerns are

1) Deleting and renaming the sheets seems unnecessarily complicated, but I was not able to get the Worksheet.Copy and Worksheet.Paste functions to play nice with each other

2) Remapping the changed sheet at the end seems unnecessary.  Is there a way to copy a spreadsheet while still retaining the XML map?  Alternatively, I currently just re-map by using a recorded macro.  Is this possible programmatically through VBA?

Here is my current code

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeXmlExport(ByVal Map As XmlMap, ByVal Url As String, Cancel As Boolean)
    Worksheets("Input Form").Copy After:=Worksheets("Input Form") 'Copies worksheet as it is prior to exporting
    Sheets("Input Form").Activate

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In Range("A1:BD4") 'Loops through worksheet.  The range would have to be changed later on
        If cl.Hyperlinks.Count <> 0 Then 'Checks cells for a link
            cl.Value = cl.Hyperlinks(1).Address & cl.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress 'If the cell has a link, change the value of the cell to its hyperlink
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AfterXmlExport(ByVal Map As XmlMap, ByVal Url As String, ByVal Result As XlXmlExportResult)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'For sheet deletion
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Efficiency, hide ugly workaround

    Worksheets("Input Form").Delete 'Deletes changed worksheet
    Worksheets("Input Form (2)").Name = "Input Form" 'Changes the name of the copy into that of the original

    Application.Run "MapXML" 'Copying seems to lose the XML map.  This macro, which I recorded manually, exists to remap.  There is probably a way to do this through VBA, although I have yet to find it.

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Properly indenting your code makes it more likely people will read your code and help you out. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: I am not sure what you question here is... What doesn't work with your current approach? Does your code throw an error?